# Redirecting correctly HTTP to HTTPS using Django and Nginx

Tags: django, nginx, https, docker-compose, nginx-location

I'm trying to redirect my website from HTTP to HTTPS and I've succeeded partially doing so. The thing is, when I type `mywebsite.fr`, I get the name of the service of the container that contains the website's code in my address bar (e.g. Django app/) with a `DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN` error.

Now, I tried the same thing with another Chrome browser of another computer and this time when I type `www.mywebsite.fr` I get the same result whereas the non-www is correctly redirected to the secure address.

Finally, I tried the exact same process using my smartphone (Brave) with the www and non-www, I get `https://djangoapp` with an error `ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED` whereas when I explicitly type `https:\\mywebsite`, I get no issues.

So here is the NGINX portion that redirects to the HTTPS server:

```
    server {
            ...

            location / {
                    return 301 https://djangoapp$request_uri;
            }
    }
```

This is the location in the HTTPS server that refers to the upstream:

```
server {
           ...

           location / {
                    ...

                    proxy_pass http://djangoapp;
            }
   }
```

And, this is the service that runs the code:

```
  djangoapp:
    build: .
    ports:
      - "8000:80"
    links:
      - db
    depends_on:
      - db
```

I do not master yet all the intricacies of NGINX and I do not really understand what I'm doing wrong here. Any solution or pieces of advice on this issue I'm having?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are returning your django app url instead of redirecting it to your http nginx block.

In your http part of config:

```
 server {
     return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
     listen 80;
 }
```

And in https, when proxy passing if you dont want the url to change to the url of your django app, you should add `proxy_set_header Host $http_host;`. It's also useful to add some additional headers like ip address. So the overal server block will look like:

```
server {
    location / {
         proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
         proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
         proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
         proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
         proxy_pass http://djangoapp;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response. The thing is I already have these settings in in the HTTPS server block so I'm not really sure the problem would come from that. You first answer was interesting, so how should I redirect to the upstream?

Answer (score 0):

My problem was resolved because my `proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto` was set to `$https` instead of `https`. Using `$scheme` as suggested also works fine.

By reading @mehrad's comment and searching a little bit on the web again, I found the bug on why the redirection was not working properly. This also includes using `$host` as opposed to `djangoapp`.